# Multi-stage docker build reactjs_nginx's first stage not take environment variable

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I use `docker compose` for the stack of `Django` + `Nginx` + `Reactjs_Nginx`. The Django and Nginx take environment variables successfully from `.env` file. But the `Reactjs_Nginx`  does not.
I tried at local for `ReactJs` and the line bellow can takes environment variable. Even running `npm run build` and `npx serve -s` it still works.

```
const hostName = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_HOST || "http://localhost:8000/";
```

After run `docker-compose up --build`, I attach shell of the `reactjs_nginx` container, and run `printenv` to check, and still see the required environment variables.
Why does the `builder` stage not take the environment variable?

```
FROM node:16.15-alpine AS builder
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /app
COPY package* /app/
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine as production
ENV NODE_ENV production
COPY --from=builder  /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    build: 
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ./docker/django/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: gunicorn resume_builder.wsgi -w ${GUNICORN_WORKER_COUNT} -b 0.0.0.0:${DJANGO_PORT}
    networks:
      - resume_builder_network

  backend_nginx:
    build: ./backend/docker/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./backend/docker/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates
    ports: 
      - "${BACKEND_PORT}:${BACKEND_PORT}"
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - resume_builder_network
    depends_on:
      - backend

  frontend:
    build: 
      context: ./frontend
      target: production
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - ${FRONTEND_PORT}:${FRONTEND_PORT}
    networks:
      - resume_builder_network

networks:
  resume_builder_network:
```

Comment: Environment variables are only available at run-time. They're not available when the image is built. You have to use build args for that: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args

Comment: Can you re-write as an answer? I tried and it works @HansKilian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are only available at run-time. They're not available when the image is built.

You have to use build args for that: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args